# Jboss - max upload file

Tags: java, jboss

I have an application with Jboss 7.1.1 and need to configure the maximum upload file, can anyone tell me how to increase its file upload max limit?
Which configuration files I have to change and how to change?
Any suggestion is very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add something like this to your web.xml file :

```
<multipart-config>
  <max-file-size>5120000</max-file-size>
  <max-request-size>5120000</max-request-size>
</multipart-config>
```

Comment: How to do this on jboss-eap-6.4 ? I can not find web.xml file anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

the http connection has settings for max post size but I'm not sure . You could do this in your web.xml